# datepicker show the date based on year - JQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am try to load the date range current year and previous year(2017,2018) based on selected dropdown. But my date picker is showing only which years first selected.

> I can show the years which is first selected. Example First selected
>   year- 2017 means show the 2017 calender Second change selected year-
>   2018 means show the 2017 calender

HTML Code:

```
 <?php $year = date('Y'); ?>
 <select name="hyear" id="hyear" data-placeholder="Select Year"  class="form-control chosen-select">                                       
     <option value="<?php echo $year ?>"><?php echo $year ?></option>      
     <option value="<?php echo ++$year ?>"><?php echo $year ?></option>                                            
 </select>
```

Script code:

```
 function updateDatePic(mindate, maxdate)
    {
        $('#hdate').datepick({
            minDate: mindate,
            maxDate: maxdate,
            onSelect: function () {

            }
        });
    }

    $('#hyear').change(function () {
        var year = $.trim($("#hyear").val());
        var mindate = '01/01/' + year;
        var maxdate = '12/31/' + year;        
        alert("mindate="+mindate+"...maxdate="+maxdate);        
        updateDatePic(mindate, maxdate);
    });
```

Please advise!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kindly use this code:

```
$( "#hdate" ).datepicker({   
    dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    yearRange: '2017:2018'
});
```

Comment: Why I cannot use `change` function to change the years?

Comment: you will work on date picker plugin when how to change the attribute in change event so kindly update the year into the datepicker yearRange Parameter

Comment: Very useful Thanks!